# React Native - Bridge iOS unit test

Tags: ios, react-native, unit-testing, testing

I'm currently working an Application which use severals Native UI components from packages that we developed.

Development works great, we already find how to develop those component in seperate xCode project and how to link them with our main application.

Problems cames when I wanted to write unit test in my bridge (there is some business logic that I must test). I looked in famous project like react-native-video, react-native-maps, async-storage and didn't find any native unit test. It surprised me a lot. I must have missed something.

Does any one have already write unit iOS test for a bridge ?Do you have any good sources for helping me ?

Thanks for your help !